# encoding special characters in java

Tags: java, encoding, character, ascii

I have a string message to display which contains special characters but it doesnt print all. For example if I give message like "The P & A company does the work".
It prints only "The P".

```
public void setOutageMsg(String outageMsg) {
        //outage msg issue
        if(outageMsg==null){
            this.outageMsg = outageMsg;
        }
        else{
            outageMsg=outageMsg.replaceAll("&amp;","&").replaceAll("&","%26");  
            this.outageMsg = outageMsg;
        }
    }
```

Similarly, I need to have a single code for all the special characters.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't print all" how are you trying to print the message? Can you please provide the code you're using to print the message?

Comment: Are you supplying this through a web page?  If so, you'd have to deal with the `&` character _before_ this method, not within it.

Comment: can u edit your code with outageMsg value

Comment: public void setOutageMsg(String outageMsg) {
        //outage msg issue
        if(outageMsg==null){
            this.outageMsg = outageMsg;
        }
        else{
            outageMsg=outageMsg.replaceAll("&amp;","&").replaceAll("&","%26");  
            this.outageMsg = outageMsg;
        }
    }

Comment: the above code worked correctly for '&' encoding but i need to have a code which works for all special characters " !@#$%*()............" any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, It may help you

```
outageMsg=outageMsg.replaceAll("&amp;","&").replaceAll("&","\u0026");
```

or

```
outageMsg=outageMsg.replaceAll("&(?!amp;)","&").replaceAll("&","\u0026");
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The code for '&' works. Now I need to encode for all the special characters which includes " % *#@()!" and do not want to seperately encode each and every character.Any suggestions?

Comment: Answer is right so why i was down voted ?
any ways your string can have all special characters or you need replace for looking for "% *#@()!" only ?

Comment: string can have all special characters.

Comment: "&(?!amp;)" is regex, you can for other special characters as well

Comment: I dont want to add seperate line of code encoding for all characters instead 1 code which will encode all special chars when i pass a String

Comment: suppose you are replacing "&(?!amp;)" with "&", and then what other special character will replace with ? Actually you need use replaceAll method for each and every special character.

Answer (score -1):

You can write something along these lines

```
    public void setOutageMsg(String outageMsg) {
            //outage msg issue
            if(outageMsg==null){
                this.outageMsg = outageMsg;
            }
            else{
                this.outageMsg = getFormattedString(outageMsg);
            }
        }

    private String getFormattedString(String outageMsg){
           outageMsg.replaceAll("&amp;","&");
           outageMsg.replaceAll("a","b");
           //...
           return outageMsg;
       }
```